# Spring boot 2.5 Not working with MySql replication driver

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm in the process of migrating a traditional war/spring application to springboot 2.5, and I'm not able to get MySql working with JPA/JDBC using mysql's replication driver:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:replication://host1:3306,rohost2:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC&logger=com.mysql.cj.log.Slf4JLogger&allowSlavesDownConnections=true&readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves=true&loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000`

The response:

nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, 'jdbc:mysql:replication://.....'

Is the replication driver not supported in Spring boot?

Comment: Why do you need replication driver for an application?

Comment: My application uses read-only nodes to improve performance as it is a multi-tenet application with over 100K users.  Use-case would be reporting, or any operation where a data read is required from the service tier without a write operation.  We use Spring's @Transactional(readOnly=true) in this case.  This vastly improves our load on our MySql databases that are running on AWS RDS using with multiple read-only replicas.

Comment: What version of `mysql:mysql-connector-java` are you using? The default with Spring Boot 2.5.x is 8.0.x where I do not believe that replication requires a separate driver. If you're using an old version of the connector, you may need to set `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` to the fully-qualified name of the replication driver.